# UICollectionViewCell alternative selectionStyle = .none

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

What is the alternative property (selectionStyle in tableViewCell) for UICollectionViewCell ? How to disable default selection gray color ?

Comment: You can use 'isSelected' property to determine cell is selected or not. Do you want to add custom color instead of default gray color for cell selection?

Answer (score 1):

**First method**, Try to change contentView background color to clear with didSelect method:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
 let cell = collectionview.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! YourCell
 cell.contentView.backgroundColor = .clear
}
```

**Second method** isSelected, in your collectionViewCell override isSelected var :

```
class YourCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

override var isSelected: Bool {
    didSet {
        self.contentView.backgroundColor = isSelected ? UIColor.yourColor : UIColor.yourColor // set your colors here
    }
}
// here the rest of your UICollectionViewCell code
```

Comment: Thanks for providing ur thoughts, the answer is - I need to write backgroundColor = .clear inside cell (or where we configure our cells to hide default behaviour)